# JSF2 Converting List of String to String[]

Tags: java, jsf-2

having a bit of a spanner moment. I need to convert a List to String Array:

`List<String> selectedIndicie` to `String[] targetIndices;`

The selectedIndicie list is pulled from a backing bean and I attempt to convert it to a String array like so:

```
setTargetIndices(initialiseBean.getSelectedIndicie().toArray(getTargetIndices()));
```

But Java has a right old moan saying:

> An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean searchBean

As I said I am having a spanner moment on how else to convert the List of Strings to an array of String so any suggests would be lovely.

Cheers

Comment: Can you split the line up a bit and see exactly which call is failing?

Comment: *"An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean searchBean"*. Please read the server logs for the entire stacktrace with the root cause. It contains your answer.

Comment: Are you doing that in the constructor? If so try moving it to a method with @PostConstruct.

Comment: @BalusC: Once I had similar kind of message. Now, I remember that actually I was trying to use EJB in the ManagedBean constructor. That was a different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`List.toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) returns an array of `Object`s, which is likely to result in an exception when you execute `setTargetIndices` for this method would be accepting an array of `String` objects. The answer is to not convert the setter to accept an array of `Object` (for the JSF runtime might simply fail to recognize the setter as belonging to the `targetIndices` property), rather it is to invoke the setter with an array of Strings.

Comment: spanner moment over: String[] targetIndices = initialiseBean.getSelectedIndicie().toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: I was wondering how you managed to get past a compiler error, and was about to delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> As I said I am having a spanner moment on how else to convert the List
>   of Strings to an array of String so any suggests would be lovely.

Use the [toArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String[] targetIndices = selectedIndicie.toArray(new String[selectedIndicie.size()]);
```